# Pandas - Take bitwise similarly and calculate weighted mean based on that

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vector, matrix-multiplication

I have a Pandas dataframe `df1` like this:

```
  ID  col1 col2 col3
0  A   1    1    1
1  B   1    1    1
2  C   1    0    1
3  D   0    0    0
4  E   1    1    1
5  F   0    1    0
6  G   1    0    0
7  H   0    1    0
```

and another dataframe `df2` like this:

```
  ID  col1 col2 col3 rating1  rating2
0  I   0    1    0     1        2
1  J   0    1    1     3        1
2  K   1    0    0     4        4
3  L   0    1    0     2        2
```

and I need to find the similarity `(x==y).sum` (not of bitwise xor) between each row of `df1` (except `ID`) with the corresponding rows in `df2` and use that similarity as a weight to compute average ratings for all the IDs in `df1`.

For example:

Final ratings of A should be computed as:

`rating1[A] = ( 1*1 + 2*3 + 1*4 + 1*2 ) / (1 + 2 + 1 + 1) = 13/5`

My output should be another dataframe having the ratings for all the IDs in `df1` after computing the similarity mean of ratings using `df2`.

Output Dataframe:

```
  ID rating1  rating2
0  A   13/5      2
1  B   13/5      2
... and so on till ID H
```

Please help me do this efficiently using pandas functions. I tried doing it by iterating over all rows, but both `df1` and `df2` are very huge tables and it is taking a lot of time.

Thanks in advance.

---

### Update

@WeNYoBen's answer is correct. Although, in my case, the dimensions of `df1` and `df2` are much higher than what I've shown here as an example.

In the third line (of @WeNYoBen's answer), the dimensions of `s` would be len(`df1`)*len(`df2`) and both of them are huge in my case and give me a MemoryError. Is there any workaround for that, in the sense that I could split `df2` into smaller parts and can compute on them individually?

Thanks again.

Comment: I think A and B should have same rating right ? since they have same value in df1

Comment: Yes, Check the updated version. Thanks for pointing that out @WeNYoBen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more like  `numpy` broadcast then `dot`

```
s1=df1.iloc[:,1:].values
s2=df2.iloc[:,1:-2].values
s=np.sum(s1[:,None]==s2,-1)
df1['rating1']=s.dot(df2.rating1)/s.sum(1)
df1['rating2']=s.dot(df2.rating2)/s.sum(1)
df1
Out[623]: 
  ID  col1  col2  col3   rating1   rating2
0  A     1     1     1  2.600000  2.000000
1  B     1     1     1  2.600000  2.000000
2  C     1     0     1  3.666667  3.000000
3  D     0     0     0  2.428571  2.428571
4  E     1     1     1  2.600000  2.000000
5  F     0     1     0  2.111111  2.000000
6  G     1     0     0  3.000000  3.200000
7  H     0     1     0  2.111111  2.000000
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am getting `DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until` warning in line 3. The shape of `s1[:, None]` is (8, 1, 2) while the shape of `s2`is (N2, 2).
I am a newbie to Pandas and numpy matrices, can you please help me fix this error.

Comment: @DevanshuSomani ah I know , updated , change _values to values

Comment: I did that but am still getting the same error. `s1` and `s2` have similar shapes. What does `s1[:, None]` do? It has converted 2d `s1` into 3d.

Comment: Actual data:

```print(s1.shape, s1[:,None].shape, s2.shape)
(3764955, 79) (3764955, 1, 79) (5544, 79)```

Comment: I figured out my error. It is actually a MemoryError because `s` becomes a numpy array of 3764955*5544 in my case. Can you suggest some alternative, so that I can split it up in parts and do the computation without exceeding the memory limit?

Comment: @DevanshuSomani split you df1, then we can do it within for loop :-), check np.split